# What are the differences between BSC and Matic that I should consider when moving a project?

Tags: blockchain, dapps, bsc, polygon

I have open source codes of a dapp project on matic network. I want to reorganize in bsc network using these open source codes. I don't know exactly which parts to change unfortunately?

Comment: Can you tell us more details about the source code? Usually EVM compatible chains have minimal differences. Obviously you shouldn't rely on contract addresses will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The Polygon (MATIC) Network is an Ethereum fork. The only changes that NEED to be made to ANY contract running ETH code is updating the addresses to whatever is appropriate to that chain or DEX.

For example:

```
WETH address: 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2
WBNB address: 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c
```